# HTML: one of two nested DIVs appears outside of parent DIV

Tags: html, nested

Such a code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {height:100px; width:200px}
body {margin:0}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background:red; height:100%">
<div style="background:green; height:100%; width:50px;">
</div>
<div style="background:yellow; height:100%;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

makes the second nested DIV appear outside of parent DIV in all browsers:

[image: wrong HTML output]

where I am expecting all the nested DIVs appear inside of parent DIV:

[image: expected HTML output]

I want the yellow DIV to fill the rest of width **regardless of parent DIV size**.

Note that `html, body {height:100px; width:200px}` is made only to make a screenshot of a decent size. It should be `html, body {height:100%; width:200%}`

**Update**

a code with `display: inline-block`:

```
<div style="background:red; height:100%">
<div style="background:green; height:100%; width:50px; display:inline-block;">
</div>
<div style="background:yellow; height:100%; display:inline-block;">
lalala
</div>
</div>
```

produces

[image]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @RyonnSan he wants it to look like example 2, but it currently looks like example 1

Comment: @Paul both of the `<div>` are `display: block`, so no matter what the second div will appear on its own line (even if you updated the width)

Comment: @Paul: can this use javascript or jQuery?

Comment: @Ryonn San: Yes, I can, but want to get all possible from HTML and CSS first. I'll use JS if nothing will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use position property of css

```
<div style="background:red; position:relative; height:100%">
<div style="background:green; height:100%;position:absolute; top:0px;left:0px; width:50px;">
</div>
<div style="background:yellow;position:absolute;left:50px;top:0px; height:100%;width:100%;">
</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zK7y2/11/)

OR
Use float property of CSS

```
<div style="background:red; height:100%">
<div style="background:green; height:100%;float:left;width:50px;">
</div>
<div style="background:yellow; height:100%;">
</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zK7y2/15/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use either position:absolute or float:left in this case.

An example for position:absolute has been answered by Ankit above

Comment: absolutes are a potential time bomb

Answer (score 2):

You can use float left for the green div:

```
<body>
    <div style="background:red; height:100%">
        <div style="background:green; height:100%; width:50px; display:inline-block; float:left"></div>
        <div style="background:yellow; height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can change the width of html/body or the red container div and the yellow div will grow/shrink appropriately:

http://jsfiddle.net/RapKB/1/

Edit:
Whoops, you don't need inline-block.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to make the layout with a table - it behaves much more predictable than a bunch of DIVs.